# How to create a event list with day and hour using table calendar

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, arraylist, calendar

So, The user have the calendar to select one day, after this he taps on the (+) button to create an event. Then, it shows the TimePicker to user select the event start hour and minute, after he write the event name and the event is showed above the calendar, (in event list). But until now i was using only the day, now, I have to set the hour too.

Method which creates the event:

```dart
Future<void> _createEvent() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Write the event name', textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Save", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),),
                onPressed: (){
                  if(_eventController.text.isEmpty) return;
                  if(_myEvents[_calendarDaySelected] != null){
                    _myEvents[_calendarDaySelected].add(_eventController.text.toString());
                    _selectedEvents = _myEvents[_calendarDaySelected];
                  }else{
                    _myEvents[_calendarDaySelected] = [_eventController.text];
                    _selectedEvents = _myEvents[_calendarDaySelected];
                  }
                  _eventController.clear();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

In this case i'm using `_myEvents[_calendarDaySelected]` so I thought to write `_myEvents[calendarDaySelected][_time]` but it throws an error:

> error: The argument type 'TimeOfDay' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

How could I do this? If you need more code, I can post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve that with this code:

`_myEvents[_calendarDaySelected].add({"time": _time, "eventName": _eventController.text.toString()});`